# Error when trying to initiate gulp on windows CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-sass

I'm trying to run a gulpfile on my pc and i get this error

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Osinowo\boot6\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Osinowo\boot6\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Osinowo\boot6\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:166:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
```

here is the version of node installed on my computer **node** `v15.3.0` and **node-sass**:

```
node-sass       5.0.0   (Wrapper)       [JavaScript]
libsass         3.5.5   (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
```

I'd appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***you should downgrade node to atleast v14***

If you go to the url mentioned in the error trace,
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1

You will see that only till node 14 is supported on windows.

[image]